# Exporting Full Custom Grid Data

Tags: module, grid, csv, export

Trying to export the full grid data of a custom module. The function itself works but there's a limit of 20 (well a limit of how many rows are visible on the page). I need to export the full data from the button. I tried adding: `$grid->setDefaultLimit(4000)` but I realised that 4000 isn't always going to be correct. So I need something to say do all data. Here's my current function:

```
<?php
    class Namespae_Module_Adminhtml_GridController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
        protected function _createSerializerBlock($inputName, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid $gridBlock, $productsArray) {
            return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_ajax_serializer')
                ->setGridBlock($gridBlock)
                ->setProducts($productsArray)
                ->setInputElementName($inputName);
        }

        public function indexAction() {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('adminhtml/grid/index');
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace_module/adminhtml_grid'));
            $this->renderLayout();
        }

        public function exportCsvAction() {
            $filename = 'inventory_report-' . date('d-m-Y') . '_' . date('H:i:s') . '.csv';
            $grid     = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace_module/adminhtml_grid');
            //$grid->setDefaultLimit(4000);

            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($filename, $grid->getCsvFile());
        }
    }
```

As I said, it all works but I need it for all data, not just what's visible on the screen.

How can I go about doing this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to extend **getCsvFile()** method?

Something like that should take of limiting and paging from your collection:

```
// ...

$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit();
$this->getCollection()->setPageSize(0);
$this->getCollection()->load();
foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
  $io->streamWriteCsv(array( // ...
```

Comment: I have not yet, will give it a go :)